# How to sum values from the inner query

Tags: sql

I have the query which solves the expression and shows 3 numbers. How can I sum this numbers as the are not relate to any column of the table

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
    (Gramms * DishCost / 100) AS PRICE
FROM 
    Portion 
INNER JOIN 
    Zakaz ON Portion.ID_Portion = Zakaz.ID_Portion
INNER JOIN 
    Dishes ON Dishes.ID_Dishes = Portion.ID_Dishes
```

It returns

```
none
6
6
75
```

How can I sum these 3 numbers to get 87?

Answer (score 0):

use `sum()`

```
SELECT sum((Gramms*DishCost/100)) AS PRICE
FROM Portion INNER JOIN Zakaz ON Portion.ID_Portion = Zakaz.ID_Portion
INNER JOIN Dishes ON Dishes.ID_Dishes = Portion.ID_Dishes
```

Answer (score 0):

add `sum()` aggregate function in your query

```
SELECT sum((Gramms*DishCost)/100) AS PRICE
FROM Portion INNER JOIN Zakaz
ON Portion.ID_Portion = Zakaz.ID_Portion
INNER JOIN Dishes
ON Dishes.ID_Dishes = Portion.ID_Dishes
```